# Include parent page in list of child pages

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I am trying to list pages for a specific ID but want to include the parent page in the list

```
<?php 
    $parent = 83;
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li'    => '',
        'child_of' => $parent,
    ) );    
?>
```

I tried adding `'include' => 83` but then it only listed the parent and not the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent with wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID()), and store it in a new variable and do the same with the children and then just showcase them in any format you want.

```
<?php
$theParent = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());

if ( $theParent->ID == 83 ) { ?>
  <div class="parent"><?PHP echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></div>
  <ul class="children"><?PHP wp_list_pages(array(
            'title_li' => '',
            'child_of' => $theParent ?> </ul>
 <?PHP } ?>
```

Hopefully, this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. I think there is firstly a syntax error. The links are meant to show in a footer on any page I am on so, the parent is going to be hardcoded, not dynamic.

Comment: What about this?  `<?php the_permalink(101); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(101); ?>`

Comment: So you are going to display this only on a specific page or on all pages ?

Comment: In the footer, so on all pages

Comment: But you still want to keep it just for that specific ID and not to be dynamic? If that's the case, perhaps you can hardcode it. Pull the children with the PHP function and hardcode the Parent name.